# Is there an R equivalent of python's string `format` function?

Tags: r, replace

In python there's a nice function (str `.format`) that can really easily replace variables (encoded like `{variable}`) in a string with values stored in a dict (with values named by variable name). Like so:

```
vars=dict(animal="shark", verb="ate", noun="fish")
string="Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}."
print(string.format(**vars))
```

> Sammy the shark ate a fish.

What is the simplest solution in `R`? Is there a built-in equivalent 2-argument function that takes a string with variables encoded **in the same 
way** and replaces them with named values from a named `list`?

If there is no built-in function in R, is there one in a published package?

If there is none in a published package, what would you use to write one?

The rules: the string is given to you with variables encoded like "{variable}". The variables must be encoded as a `list`. I will answer with my custom-made version, but will accept an answer that does it better than I did.

Comment: I'll pretty confidently stick my neck out and say "no". Not built in to base R. There may be something exactly like this in add-on packages. There are *similar* things for doing variable replacement (eg the brew package) but you want the format exactly coded with this {name} syntax, yes?

Comment: Yes; the string is already built for python-centric analysis, so I cannot change the way the variables are encoded.

Comment: `brew` uses `<%=` and `%>` as markers. Replacing `{` and `}` with those would work if you don't expect `<%=` in the string or have escaped `{}` anywhere.

Comment: I don't know any equivalent of the format function in R, but you have an equivalent of the printf C function which allows you to put what you want to print, and the list of variables. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.5.0/topics/printf

Comment: `sprintf()` is the closest there is in the core packages.  It doesn't use named replacement groups, but can do indexed groups: `sprintf("%1$s %1$s %2$s %3$s", "a", "b", "c")`

Comment: Use bquote and wrap it in as.character?

Comment: The `format` function in the `jmvcore` package on CRAN does exactly this - it doesn't have the same syntax as Python for including literal curly brackets though - Python uses `{{` to put a `{` in the output.

Comment: There's also `%f%` in the `stringformattr` package, giving : `"Hello {thing}" %f% c(thing="world")`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I found another solution: glue package from the tidyverse: 
https://github.com/tidyverse/glue

An example:

```
library(glue)
animal <- "shark"
verb <- "ate"
noun <- "fish"
string="Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}."
glue(string)
Sammy the shark ate a fish.
```

If you insist on having list of variables, you can do:

```
l <- list(animal = "shark", verb = "ate", noun = "fish")
do.call(glue, c(string , l))
Sammy the shark ate a fish.
```

Regards

Paweł

Comment: It's better to use `with`: `with(l, glue(string))`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) package *almost* has an exact replacement in the function `str_interp`. it requires just a bit of adjustment:

```
fmt = function(str, vals) {
    # str_interp requires variables encoded like ${var}, so we substitute
    # the {var} syntax here.
    str = stringr::str_replace_all(str, "\\{", "${")
    stringr::str_interp(str, vals)
}
```

Comment: buggy example...passes in 'str' and 'vals', references 'x' and 'args'.

Comment: fixed the args so they match

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that converts the `{` and `}` to `<%=` and `%>` and then uses `brew` from the `brew` package (which you need to install):

```
form = function(s,...){
 s = gsub("\\}", "%>", gsub("\\{","<%=",s))
 e = as.environment(list(...))
 parent.env(e)=.GlobalEnv
 brew(text=s, envir=e)
}
```

Tests:

```
> form("Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}.", animal = "shark", verb="made", noun="car")
Sammy the shark made a car.
> form("Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}.", animal = "shark", verb="made", noun="truck")
Sammy the shark made a truck.
```

It will fail if there's any `{` in the format string that don't mark variable substitutions, or if it has `<%=` or any of the other `brew` syntax markers in it.

Comment: This is more concise than my version -- but I think it would be more useful if it accepted a `list` of variables

Comment: Try `form = function(s,L){` and `e = as.environment(L)` in that case (untested). I was basing mine on python's string format method which doesn't actually take a dict, but an argument list (which you can convert with stars, as the OP has now done in an edit!

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears I cannot find a built-in or even a package with such a function, I tried to roll my own. My function relies on the `stringi` package. Here is what I have come up with:

```
strformat = function(str, vals) {
    vars = stringi::stri_match_all(str, regex = "\\{.*?\\}", vectorize_all = FALSE)[[1]][,1]
    x = str
    for (i in seq_along(names(vals))) {
        varName = names(vals)[i]
        varCode = paste0("{", varName, "}")
        x = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, varCode, vals[[varName]], vectorize_all = TRUE)
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Example:

```
> str = "Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}."
> vals = list(animal="shark", verb="ate", noun="fish")

> strformat(str, vals)
[1] "Sammy the shark ate a fish."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(glue)

list2env(list(animal="shark", verb="ate", noun="fish"),.GlobalEnv)
string="Sammy the {animal} {verb} a {noun}."
glue(string)

Sammy the shark ate a fish.
```